# Perform Click on button in a grid

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am new to UWP/XAML but I've been using .NET for quite a while now. I have an issue as follows.

I have an app which shows a Customer page. I've added a VariableSizedWrapGrid and called a sub to fill it with buttons as follows:

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="FirstChars" Orientation="Horizontal"/>

       // Create first button '#' with character and Click event and add to grid
        ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton { Content = '#', Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(2, 0, 0, 0), Width = 34 };
        btn.Click += FirstChars_Click;
        FirstChars.Children.Add(btn);
        // Create all alphabets buttons and Click event and add to grid
        char[] az = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(i => (Char)i).ToArray();
        foreach (var c in az)
        {
            btn = new ToggleButton { Content = c, Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(2, 0, 0, 0), Width = 34 };
            btn.Click += FirstChars_Click;
            FirstChars.Children.Add(btn);
        }
```

[image]

When the user enters this page, no buttons is selected and I want to perform a click event on the first button "A" so that I can then perform the appropriate Select query on my DB.

How do I select the button and call the appropriate event when the page has been loaded?

I'm guessing I need to define a ToggleButton variable and select the button from the grid which has the content "A". But I can't fathom how to do this after many tries :(

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor after foreach loop, you can subscribe to the Loaded event like this

```
this.Loaded += OnPageLoaded;
```

After subscribing to the above event, you can check for load the content for "A" toggle button and load its information at page startup.

```
private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in FirstChars.Children)
    {
        if (item is ToggleButton button && button.Content.ToString().Equals("A"))
        {
            button.IsChecked = true;
            // Perform your query here or call the appropriate method
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some method like Loaded or Initialized, why don't you factor out what you want to run from the event handler into a separate method and call it from both places?